# Exchange 2010 admin viewing all calanders

Tags: exchange-2010

We have just moved from exchange 2003 to 2010 and I have suddenly lost the ability to view all my users calendar I need to ask permission and do it one by one. I used to enter the security setting and not see my name but still be an admin on that calendar.

I was told that I can not gain access to all calendars at once .

Is there a way to gain access to all exchange accounts under my group without going one by one .

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2010 this is managed with the Set-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet in powershell/EMS. [This article](http://blog.powershell.no/2010/09/20/managing-calendar-permissions-in-exchange-server-2010/) explains a little more, and links to a [Powershell script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/19b98a56-42aa-4695-b07c-335d8322b64e/) that updates permissions on all calendars to be viewable by all users.

If you only want to set this permission for your own account, replace the "Default" in the last command with your own username, so it says (if your domain and username where domain.local\admin-yaar):

`Set-MailboxFolderPermission -User "domain.local\admin-yaar" -AccessRights $AccessRights -Identity $calendar` instead